# _type property included in asp.net page method result data

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods

I have a page method to get the list.
I can get the result from this method, in this result object contains _type:'MyNamespace+ClassName'.
I want to get the result with out this property.
How to do this? or else we need to remove this property manually.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to call JavaScript's [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) method on the result.